# Persisting data cosmos not working

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I'm trying to persist the information received in Orion in the public instance of Cosmos, but I get an http 500 error. This is the contextBroker log:

```
function=sendHttpSocket | comp=Orion | msg=clientSocketHttp.cpp[154]: Starting transaction to localhost:5060/notify
function=sendHttpSocket | comp=Orion | msg=clientSocketHttp.cpp[364]: Notification Successfully Sent to localhost:5060/notify
function=sendHttpSocket | comp=Orion | msg=clientSocketHttp.cpp[375]: Transaction ended
function=connectionTreat | comp=Orion | msg=rest.cpp[767]: Starting transaction from 192.168.201.95:49160/v1/updateContext
function=processContextElement | comp=Orion | msg=MongoCommonUpdate.cpp[1647]: Database Operation Successful ({ _id.id: "613cb7464a7950ba", _id.type: "UMANICK_TECHNOLOGIES", _id.servicePath: /^\/$|^\/\/.*/ })
function=addTriggeredSubscriptions | comp=Orion | msg=MongoCommonUpdate.cpp[922]: Database Operation Successful ({ $or: [ { entities.id: "613cb7464a7950ba", $or: [ { entities.type: "UMANICK_TECHNOLOGIES" }, { entities.type: { $exists: false } } ], entities.isPattern: "false", conditions.type: "ONCHANGE", conditions.value: "X_VALUE", expiration: { $gt: 1435574837 }, servicePath: { $in: [ /^$|^/#$|^/$/, null ] } }, { entities.isPattern: "true", conditions.type: "ONCHANGE", conditions.value: "X_VALUE", expiration: { $gt: 1435574837 }, servicePath: { $in: [ /^$|^/#$|^/$/, null ] }, $where: function(){for (var i=0; i < this.entities.length; i++) {if (this.enti... } ] })
function=addTriggeredSubscriptions | comp=Orion | msg=MongoCommonUpdate.cpp[922]: Database Operation Successful ({ $or: [ { entities.id: "613cb7464a7950ba", $or: [ { entities.type: "UMANICK_TECHNOLOGIES" }, { entities.type: { $exists: false } } ], entities.isPattern: "false", conditions.type: "ONCHANGE", conditions.value: "Z_VALUE", expiration: { $gt: 1435574837 }, servicePath: { $in: [ /^$|^/#$|^/$/, null ] } }, { entities.isPattern: "true", conditions.type: "ONCHANGE", conditions.value: "Z_VALUE", expiration: { $gt: 1435574837 }, servicePath: { $in: [ /^$|^/#$|^/$/, null ] }, $where: function(){for (var i=0; i < this.entities.length; i++) {if (this.enti... } ] })
function=processContextElement | comp=Orion | msg=MongoCommonUpdate.cpp[1834]: Database Operation Successful (update { _id.id: "613cb7464a7950ba", _id.type: "UMANICK_TECHNOLOGIES", _id.servicePath: /\// })
function=entitiesQuery | comp=Orion | msg=MongoGlobal.cpp[1090]: Database Operation Successful ({ query: { $or: [ { _id.id: "613cb7464a7950ba", _id.type: "UMANICK_TECHNOLOGIES" } ], _id.servicePath: { $in: [ null, /^/$/ ] }, attrs.name: { $in: [ "X_VALUE", "Y_VALUE", "Z_VALUE" ] } }, orderby: { creDate: 1 } })
function=processSubscriptions | comp=Orion | msg=MongoCommonUpdate.cpp[1046]: Database Operation Successful (update: { $set: { lastNotification: 1435574837 }, $inc: { count: 1 } }, query: { _id: ObjectId('55912126a85d63ed38229b6d') })
function=requestCompleted | comp=Orion | msg=rest.cpp[382]: Transaction ended
```

The subscription Orion is working properly, the Cygnus agent receives the notification, but when try to persist data in Cosmos gives an http 500 error.

```
[SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] (es.tid.fiware.orionconnectors.cosmosinjector.OrionHDFSSink.persist:212)  - Persisting data. File: 613cb7464a7950ba-UMANICK_TECHNOLOGIES-X_VALUE-float.txt, Data: 2015-06-29T12:50:18.763|1435575018|613cb7464a7950ba|UMANICK_TECHNOLOGIES|X_VALUE|float|0.30645782)
[SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] (es.tid.fiware.orionconnectors.cosmosinjector.hdfs.HttpFSBackend.exists:158)  - HttpFS operation: GET http://130.206.80.46:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/ilko.garcia/mydataset/613cb7464a7950ba-UMANICK_TECHNOLOGIES-X_VALUE-float.txt?op=getfilestatus&user.name=ilko.garcia HTTP/1.1
[SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] (es.tid.fiware.orionconnectors.cosmosinjector.hdfs.HttpFSBackend.exists:161)  - HttpFS response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] (es.tid.fiware.orionconnectors.cosmosinjector.hdfs.HttpFSBackend.append:123)  - HttpFS operation: POST http://130.206.80.46:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/ilko.garcia/mydataset/613cb7464a7950ba-UMANICK_TECHNOLOGIES-X_VALUE-float.txt?op=append&user.name=ilko.garcia HTTP/1.1
[SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] (es.tid.fiware.orionconnectors.cosmosinjector.hdfs.HttpFSBackend.append:126)  - HttpFS response: HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
[SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] (es.tid.fiware.orionconnectors.cosmosinjector.hdfs.HttpFSBackend.append:138)  - HttpFS operation: POST http://130.206.80.46:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/ilko.garcia/mydataset/613cb7464a7950ba-UMANICK_TECHNOLOGIES-X_VALUE-float.txt?op=append&user.name=ilko.garcia&data=true HTTP/1.1
[SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] (es.tid.fiware.orionconnectors.cosmosinjector.hdfs.HttpFSBackend.append:141)  - HttpFS response: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

My Cygnus agent configuration file is as follows:

```
# APACHE_FLUME_HOME/conf/cygnus.conf
orionagent.sources = http-source
orionagent.sinks = hdfs-sink
orionagent.channels = notifications

# Flume source, must not be changed
orionagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
# channel name where to write the notification events
orionagent.sources.http-source.channels = notifications
# listening port the Flume source will use for receiving incoming notifications
orionagent.sources.http-source.port = 5060
# Flume handler that will parse the notifications, must not be changed
orionagent.sources.http-source.handler = es.tid.fiware.orionconnectors.cosmosinjector.OrionRestHandler
# regular expression for the orion version the notifications will have in their headers
orionagent.sources.http-source.handler.orion_version = 0\.19\.*
# URL target
orionagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify

# channel name from where to read notification events
orionagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = notifications
# Flume sink that will process and persist in HDFS the notification events, must not be changed
orionagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = es.tid.fiware.orionconnectors.cosmosinjector.OrionHDFSSink
# IP address of the Cosmos deployment where the notification events will be persisted
orionagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.cosmos_host = 130.206.80.46
# port of the Cosmos service listening for persistence operations; 14000 for httpfs, 50070 for webhdfs and free choice for inifinty
orionagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.cosmos_port = 14000
# username allowed to write in HDFS (/user/myusername)
orionagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.cosmos_username = ilko.garcia
orionagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.cosmos_default_password = *************
# dataset where to persist the data (/user/myusername/mydataset)
orionagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.cosmos_dataset = mydataset
# HDFS backend type (webhdfs, httpfs or infinity)
orionagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_api = httpfs
# how the attributes are stored, either per row either per column (row, column)
orionagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.attr_persistence = column


# channel name
orionagent.channels.notifications.type = memory
# capacity of the channel
orionagent.channels.notifications.capacity = 1000
# amount of bytes that can be sent per transaction
orionagent.channels.notifications.transactionCapacity = 100
```

My Orion instance it's on spain2 region.

Thanks in advance.

======================================================================
**EDIT 1**

I installed the new version of Cygnus (0.8.1), but does not catch on boot agent settings created.

Here you can see the log flume and configuration files Cygnus.

**flume.log**

```
msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[67] : Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication[238] : Starting Cygnus application
msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[67] : jetty-6.1.26
msg=org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider[61] : Configuration provider starting
msg=org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable[133] : Reloading configuration file:/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_umanick.conf
msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:hdfs-sink
msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:hdfs-sink
msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:hdfs-sink
msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:hdfs-sink
msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:hdfs-sink
msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:hdfs-sink
msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[930] : Added sinks: hdfs-sink Agent: cygnusagent
msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:hdfs-sink
msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[336] : Agent configuration for 'cygnusagent' does not contain any valid channels. Marking it as invalid.
msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[127] : Agent configuration invalid for agent 'cygnusagent'. It will be removed.
msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[140] : Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: []
msg=org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider[138] : No configuration found for this host:cygnusagent
msg=org.apache.flume.node.Application[138] : Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{} sinkRunners:{} channels:{} }
msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[67] : Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8081
msg=org.apache.flume.node.Application[101] : Shutting down configuration: { sourceRunners:{} sinkRunners:{} channels:{} }
msg=org.apache.flume.node.Application[138] : Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{} sinkRunners:{} channels:{} }
```

**agent_umanick.conf**

```
#=============================================
# To be put in APACHE_FLUME_HOME/conf/cygnus.conf
#
# General configuration template explaining how to setup a sink of each of the available types (HDFS, CKAN, MySQL).

#=============================================
# The next tree fields set the sources, sinks and channels used by Cygnus. You could use different names than the
# ones suggested below, but in that case make sure you keep coherence in properties names along the configuration file.
# Regarding sinks, you can use multiple types at the same time; the only requirement is to provide a channel for each
# one of them (this example shows how to configure 3 sink types at the same time). Even, you can define more than one
# sink of the same type and sharing the channel in order to improve the performance (this is like having
# multi-threading).
cygnusagent.sources = http-source
cygnusagent.sinks = hdfs-sink
cygnusagent.channels = hdfs-channel

#=============================================
# source configuration
# channel name where to write the notification events
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = hdfs-channel
# source class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
# listening port the Flume source will use for receiving incoming notifications
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
# Flume handler that will parse the notifications, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler
# URL target
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
# Number of channel re-injection retries before a Flume event is definitely discarded (-1 means infinite retries)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 10


# ============================================
# OrionHDFSSink configuration
# channel name from where to read notification events
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = hdfs-channel
# sink class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionHDFSSink
# Comma-separated list of FQDN/IP address regarding the HDFS Namenode endpoints
# If you are using Kerberos authentication, then the usage of FQDNs instead of IP addresses is mandatory
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_host = 130.206.80.46
# port of the HDFS service listening for persistence operations; 14000 for httpfs, 50070 for webhdfs
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_port = 14000
# username allowed to write in HDFS
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_username = ilko.garcia
# password for the username
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_password = *************
# how the attributes are stored, either per row either per column (row, column)
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.attr_persistence = column
```

**cygnus_instance_umanick.conf**

```
# The OS user that will be running Cygnus. Note this must be `root` if you want to run cygnus in a privileged port (<1024), either the admin port or the port in which Cygnus receives Orion notifications
CYGNUS_USER=cygnus
# Which is the config folder
CONFIG_FOLDER=/usr/cygnus/conf
# Which is the config file
CONFIG_FILE=/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_umanick.conf
# Name of the agent. The name of the agent is not trivial, since it is the base for the Flume parameters naming conventions, e.g. it appears in <AGENT_NAME>.sources.http-source.channels=...
AGENT_NAME=orion
# Name of the logfile located at /var/log/cygnus. It is important to put the extension '.log' in order to the log rotation works properly
LOGFILE_NAME=cygnus.log
# Administration port. Must be unique per instance
ADMIN_PORT=8081
# Polling interval (seconds) for the configuration reloading
POLLING_INTERVAL=30
```

======================================================================
**EDIT 2**

I added the missing properties and the agent starts properly. But the data is still not persist in cosmos. Agent configuration is the same, with added properties missing

**flume.log**

```
msg=org.apache.flume.node.Application[145] : Starting Channel hdfs-channel
msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[94] : Component type: CHANNEL, name: hdfs-channel started
msg=org.apache.flume.node.Application[173] : Starting Sink hdfs-sink
msg=org.apache.flume.node.Application[184] : Starting Source http-source
msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[67] : jetty-6.1.26
msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[67] : Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:5050
msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[94] : Component type: SOURCE, name: http-source started
msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.backends.http.HttpClientFactory[79] : Setting max total connections (500)
msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.backends.http.HttpClientFactory[80] : Settubg default max connections per route (100)
msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionHDFSSink[257] : [hdfs-sink] Startup completed
msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler[150] : Starting transaction (1435685260-766-0000000000)
msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler[236] : Received data ({  "subscriptionId" : "5592bbe2a85d63e738d33bac",  "originator" : "localhost",  "contextResponses" : [    {      "contextElement" : {        "type" : "UMANICK_TECHNOLOGIES_S_L",        "isPattern" : "false",        "id" : "613cb7464a7950ba",        "attributes" : [          {            "name" : "X_VALUE",            "type" : "float",            "value" : "0.15322891"          },          {            "name" : "Y_VALUE",            "type" : "float",            "value" : "-0.076614454"          },          {            "name" : "Z_VALUE",            "type" : "float",            "value" : "9.844957"          }        ]      },      "statusCode" : {        "code" : "200",        "reasonPhrase" : "OK"      }    }  ]})
msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler[258] : Event put in the channel (id=220543398, ttl=10)
msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink[128] : Event got from the channel (id=220543398, headers={content-type=application/json, transactionId=1435685260-766-0000000000, fiware-service=def_serv, fiware-servicepath=def_serv_path, ttl=10}, bodyLength=722)
msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink[184] : null
msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink[193] : Finishing transaction (1435685260-766-0000000000)
```

======================================================================
**EDIT 3**

**flume.log**

```
Starting transaction (1435739504-848-0000000005)
Received data ({  "subscriptionId" : "5592bbe2a85d63e738d33bac",  "originator" : "localhost",  "contextResponses" : [    {      "contextElement" : {        "type" : "UMANICK_TECHNOLOGIES_S_L",        "isPattern" : "false",        "id" : "613cb7464a7950ba",        "attributes" : [          {            "name" : "X_VALUE",            "type" : "float",            "value" : "0.22984336"          },          {            "name" : "Y_VALUE",            "type" : "float",            "value" : "-0.11492168"          },          {            "name" : "Z_VALUE",            "type" : "float",            "value" : "9.921572"          }        ]      },      "statusCode" : {        "code" : "200",        "reasonPhrase" : "OK"      }    }  ]})
Event put in the channel (id=1449000407, ttl=10)
Event got from the channel (id=1449000407, headers={timestamp=1435739601153, content-type=application/json, transactionId=1435739504-848-0000000005, fiware-service=def_serv, fiware-servicepath=def_servpath, ttl=10, destination=613cb7464a7950ba_umanick_technologies_s_l}, bodyLength=721)
Persisting data at OrionHDFSSink. HDFS file (def_serv/def_servpath/613cb7464a7950ba_umanick_technologies_s_l/613cb7464a7950ba_umanick_technologies_s_l.txt), Data ({"recvTime":"2015-07-01T08:33:21.153Z","X_VALUE":"0.22984336", "X_VALUE_md":[],"Y_VALUE":"-0.11492168", "Y_VALUE_md":[],"Z_VALUE":"9.921572", "Z_VALUE_md":[]})
Finishing transaction (1435739504-848-0000000005)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using a pretty old version of Cygnus. Packages such as `es.tid.fiware.orionconnectors.cosmosinjector...` were replaced some time ago.

Please, refer to the last version in the master branch at https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus (it matches 0.8.1) or configure the FIWARE repo in order to get the RPM for 0.7.1 as described at https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus#section4.1

**EDIT 1**

Please observe this log:

```
msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[336] : Agent configuration for 'cygnusagent' does not contain any valid channels. Marking it as invalid.
```

It you have a look on your `agent_umanick.conf` file, you will see it is missing something like:

```
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-channel.type = memory
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-channel.capacity = 10000
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

Check it at https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/README.md#section5.2

**EDIT 2**

Again, if you have a look on https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/README.md#section5.2 you will see you are missing some important configuration parameters in the source and the sink:

```
# Default service (service semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = def_serv
# Default service path (service path semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = def_servpath
# Source interceptors, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
# TimestampInterceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
# GroupingInterceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder
# Grouping rules for the GroupingIntercetor, put the right absolute path to the file if necessary
# See the doc/design/interceptors document for more details
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf

# Hive FQDN/IP address of the Hive server
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive_host = cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org
# Hive port for Hive external table provisioning
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive_port = 10000
# Kerberos-based authentication enabling
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.krb5_auth = false
```

Among them, it is very important `/usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf` exists, even if it is empty. The software provides a template called `grouping_rules.conf.template`; please rename/copy it in order to have the appropriate file.

**EDIT 3**

Command to be executed in order to read the persisted data:

```
hadoop fs -cat /user/ilko.garcia/def_serv/def_servpath/613cb7464a7950ba_umanick_technologies_s_l/613cb7464a7950ba_umanick_technologies_s_l.txt
```

Comment: I modified my question with a new problem  @frb

Comment: Nice yo installed 0.8.1 :) I've edited my answer with updated comments.

Comment: The agent starts but does not persist information in cosmos. I added the log in question @frb

Comment: Adding the missing properties, the agent works, but in the cosmos folder is not the txt file. What parameter have to change to save the txt file in my cosmos folder? I'm updated mi question with flume.log

Comment: You got it! Try it with this command: `hadoop fs -cat /user/ilko.garcia/def_serv/def_servpath/613cb7464a7950ba_umanick_technologies_s_l/613cb7464a7950ba_umanick_technologies_s_l.tx`. Please observe the user data is always under `/user/<your_cosmos_user>/`, in this case `/user/ilko.garcia`.

Comment: The command return this:`[ilko.garcia@cosmosmaster-gi ~]$ hadoop fs -cat /user/ilko.garcia/def_serv/def_servpath/613cb7464a7950ba_umanick_technologies_s_‌​l/613cb7464a7950ba_umanick_technologies_s_l.txtcat: File does not exist: /user/ilko.garcia/def_serv/def_servpath/613cb7464a7950ba_umanick_technologies_s_‌​l/613cb7464a7950ba_umanick_technologies_s_l.txt`

Comment: Yes, it is there: `hadoop fs -cat /user/ilko.garcia/def_serv/def_servpath/613cb7464a7950ba_umanick_technologies_s_l/613cb7464a7950ba_umanick_technologies_s_l.txt | head -n 1
{"recvTimeTs":"1435732426","recvTime":"2015-07-01T06:33:46.694Z","entityId":"613cb7464a7950ba","entityType":"UMANICK_TECHNOLOGIES_S_L","attrName":"X_VALUE","attrType":"float","attrValue":"0.2681506","attrMd":[]}`. Please, be careful because If you tried to copy the command directly from my previous comment then a line feed or something like that is added. I'll edit my answer in order the command appears in a single line.